# display only some of valid expressions

Tags: prolog

I have some facts which are:

```
num(one)
num(two)
num(three)
```

Then i have a predicate:

```
validValue(value(Num, Num1, Num2, Num2, Num4)) :-
num(Num), num(Num1), num(Num2), num(Num3), num(num4).
```

I now want to write a query which outputs a valid

```
value(num,num1,num2,num3,num4)
```

but I want it to display only valid outputs with a num(two) and a num(three) in them.
For example, valid:

```
value(two,one,one,one,three)
```

invalid

```
value(two,one,one,one,one)
```

My train of thought was to assign X to two, Y to three, or something of the such and use

```
validValue(value(X)).
```

but that obviously just equates to:

```
validValue(value(two)).
```

Anyone able to show me what i'm doing wrong?
Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "generate and test" approach, you need to test if something holds for the arguments of a term.

For a list, it is easy. To say that a `List` contains at least one of `Element`, you can use `memberchk/2`:

```
memberchk(Element, List)
```

You can also make a list out of the arguments of a term using the univ operator `=../2`:

```
Value =.. [value|Vs]
```

In other words, you could have written:

```
is_valid(Value) :-
    Value =.. [value|Vs],
    memberchk(two, Vs), memberchk(three, Vs).
```

The only advantage is that if the term changes arity (suddenly you have one more or less value in it), you don't have to re-write the predicate.

To make a predicate that checks that each member of a list appears at least once as an argument in a term, you would write:

```
any_nums_value(Nums, Value) :-
    Value =.. [value|Vs],
    member(N, Nums),
    memberchk(N, Vs).
```

Then:

```
% generate
?- valid(V).
V = value(one, one, one, one, one) ;
V = value(one, one, one, one, two) ;
V = value(one, one, one, one, three) ;
V = value(one, one, one, two, one) .

% generate and test
?- valid(V), any_nums_value([two, three], V).
V = value(one, one, one, one, two) ;
V = value(one, one, one, one, three) ;
V = value(one, one, one, two, one) ;
V = value(one, one, one, two, two) .
```

In `any_nums_value/2` above, the conjunction `member(N, Nums), memberchk(N, Vs)` means:

> There is a member of `Nums` that appears at least once in `Vs`

If instead you need to say:

> Every member of `Nums` appears at least once in `Vs`

Then you would need to write:

```
all_nums_value(Nums, Value) :-
    Value =.. [value|Vs],
    maplist(list_check_member(Vs), Nums).

list_check_member(List, Member) :-
    memberchk(Member, List).
```

`list_check_member/2` is necessary so that the argument order fits into how `maplist` works.

Then:

```
?- valid(V), all_nums_value([two, three], V).
V = value(one, one, one, two, three) ;
V = value(one, one, one, three, two) ;
V = value(one, one, two, one, three) ;
V = value(one, one, two, two, three) .
% and so on
```

BTW, I have defined `valid/1` as:

```
valid(value(A,B,C,D,E)) :-
    maplist(num, [A,B,C,D,E]).
```

If you wanted to make valid values of lentgth N, you could write:

```
valid_n(V, N) :-
    length(Vs, N),
    maplist(num, Vs),
    V =.. [value|Vs].


?- valid_n(V, 3).
V = value(one, one, one) ;
V = value(one, one, two) ;
V = value(one, one, three) ;
V = value(one, two, one) .
% and so on

?- valid_n(V, 10).
V = value(one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one, one) .
% and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Boris. The only issue is, one can exist in the list, but there must always be a two and a three. So 1,1,1,2,3 is valid, but 1,1,1,1,2 is not valid because it's missing the 3, so it's any combination of the three numbers where a two and a three occur at least once.

Comment: When you use "valid(V), good_nums_value([two, three], V)." it seems to output values where two AND three don't exist in the same output. Such as V = value(one,one,one,one,two); this is invalid because three doesn't exist. Sorry to mess you around, I should have been more clear about that.

So it's only valid if two AND three both exist in the value. So One,One,One,Two,Three is valid, but One,One,One,One,Two isn't because three needs to appear at least once as well.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer again. If you look carefully, you should see that the predicate `is_valid/2` as defined in my answer would already give you what you are looking for. `all_nums_value/2` is just a generalization of this.

Answer (score 2):

Soo If I understand you correctly something like this would do:

```
%% facts
num(one).
num(two).
num(three).

two(two).
three(three).

%% rules
validValue(Val) :-
    contains_two(Val),
    contains_three(Val),
    valid_numbers(Val).

valid_numbers(value(Num, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4)):-
    num(Num),
    num(Num1),
    num(Num2),
    num(Num3),
    num(Num4).


contains_two(value(Num, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4)):-
    two(Num);
    two(Num1);
    two(Num2);
    two(Num3);
    two(Num4).

contains_three(value(Num, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4)):-
    three(Num);
    three(Num1);
    three(Num2);
    three(Num3);
    three(Num4).


test:-
    validValue(value(two,one,one,one,three)),
\+ validValue(value(two,one,one,one,one)).
```

This would validate all values containing a three and a two and where all numbers are valid numbers.

And you can also make queries to find valid numbers ,for example:

```
?- validValue(value(Num, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4)).
Num = two,
Num1 = three,
Num2 = Num3, Num3 = Num4, Num4 = one
```

If you want all possible numbers you can query:

```
?- findall(X, validValue(X), Result).
Result = [value(two, three, one, one, one), value(two, three, one, one, two), value(two, three, one, one, three), value(two, three, one, two, one), value(two, three, one, two, two), value(two, three, one, two, three), value(two, three, one, three, one), value(two, three, one, three, two), value(..., ..., ..., ..., ...)|...].
```

Comment: I think maybe I worded the question wrong.
But basically I want every set of numbers that contain both 2 and 3 within the 5 digit value. I tried above query and was getting values that existed a 2, but not a 3, and vice versa

Comment: Yes so when I type ?- validValue(X). for example it will give 1,1,1,1,1 then 1,1,1,1,2... so on until every combination of the 3 numbers has been exhausted. But I want to do this again, but only showing the values with a 2 and a 3 in them. So it would remove 1,1,1,1,1 as this doesn't contain a 3 or 2, and would start with something like 1,1,1,2,3

Comment: If you use the code I've pasted you cannot get values that does'nt contain both 2 and 3.  See updated answer for how you can query to get a whole list of all numbers.

Comment: If you want to query for valid values that doesnt have to contains 2 or 3 you can still do so, just use the predicate `valid_numbers` which is the same as the original predicate `validValue` that you posted.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm only new to prolog so still trying to get my head around your code.